# Surjections of functions and proof by counterexample

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Here is the question:

$f : X \mapsto Y$ and $g : Y \mapsto Z$ are functions.

(a) Prove that if $g \circ f: X \mapsto Z$ is a surjection, then $g$ is a surjection.

(b) Give a counterexample to show that the converse is not true.

My proof was as follows:

(a) $g \circ f$ is a surjection $\implies$ $\forall z \in Z$, $\exists x \in X$ : $z = g\circ f (x)$

But $\exists y \in Y$ : $y = f(x)$

Thus $\forall z \in Z$, $\exists y \in Y$ : $z = g(y)$

$\therefore g$ is surjective.

(b) Suppose that $f : ${1} $\mapsto$ {2, 3} and $g : ${2, 3} $\mapsto$ {4, 5}

Now let $g(2) = 4$ and $g(3) = 5$. This makes $g$ a bijection and therefore a surjection. Also let $f(1) = 3$. Then $g \circ f = 5$ and 4 is left out of the mapping, so $g \circ f$ is not a surjection.

Is this correct? I'm self taught so I don't have a way of checking.

Comment: Yes, your arguments look correct to me. (b) is even easier if you consider that the cardinality of $X$ is $1$ and the cardinality of $Z$ is $2$, that is, there can be no surjection from $X$ to $Z$ with $|X| < |Z|$.

Comment: Thanks and yes you're right! There are so many ways of tackling part (b). I used sets of numbers rather than cardinalities but it gets the same point across I suppose. Cardinalities give a nice way of describing the pigeonhole principle as well. It's a shame functions don't seem a popular topic with a lot of undergraduate students.

Comment: Giving an explicit example with a mapping of elements is always very persuasive. So, all is well with your line of reasoning. If you are self-taught  (as am I mostly) you could check out "Naive Set Theory" by P. Halmos  (ISBN-10: 1614271313); it is quite cheap and very beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

function f is not function there since it has only 1 element in domain and codomain has more elements.It is against the definition of function. This makes your argument wrong.f(1) can also be 2 instead and makes g not surjection.

Comment: It is my understanding that the definition of a function is "a rule that assigns a unique element of the codomain to each element of the domain". What I have done does not go against this definition, since the only element of the domain is involved in the matching. I really don't understand what you mean by "f(1) = 2 makes g not surjection" because as far as I can see this wouldn't be true

Comment: Also, the mapping I have described does not map the one element of the domain X to both elements in Y, so it isn't "one to many" and that should't go against the rules

Comment: @user356478 http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/function.html you can read "two important thing" 2nd point and get some more clarity about what function is

Comment: I thought that was the range? You can have functions that don't map to every value of the codomain.

Comment: I can't find your original comment but it read something like "codomain is the set of all images". This would contradict what I have seen in other questions where some elements of the codomain were left unmatched. Is it not true that the images are a subset of the codomain?